# Pass chrome options to new Opened tab by clicking on an element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I facing a problem i.e. I pass few Chrome Arguments while Chrome Driver like this,

```
chrome_options = Webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debuggin-port=9225")
webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

element.click()   #This will open a new chrome tab
```

Now when I clicked on an element on the Chrome Page, it will open a new tab but above chrome options are not working on that tab.

Comment: You got a typo in your code?  `chrome_opotions.` vs `chrome_options`

Comment: Thanks, but in original code there is no Type

Comment: how about this typo?  `--remote-debuggin-port` vs `--remote-debugging-port`  - can you copy the code exactly as you have it? :-)

Comment: Are you trying to change chrome options on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you opened more than one chrome tab you need to specify which of the opened tabs you want to get your code going on for.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'link to chromedriver') #adds own options 
driver.execute_script("window.open('link to website', 'create a variable for the website')")
driver.switch_to.window('variable for the website')
```

From now on, the driver will be working with the following code.

If you want the driver to work on another website, you'll just have to exectue this script:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('link to the website', 'variable for the website')")
driver.switch_to.window('variable for the website')
```

Hope I could help you !